# My game crashes when I try to pick up a power-up in alien invasion in my python program

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and I am trying to follow the project of creating alien invasion from the book "Crash course Python". I wanted to add some stuff of my own like power-up. The power-ups now have a chance to spawn where an alien dies and they travel downwards but when I pick up a power-up my game crashes without leaving an error message. I don't know how to proceed.

I have two power-ups. One has to increase the number of bullets that you can shoot and the other is a power shot that will let your next shot pierce through aliens.

First the code for my powerups class:

```
import pygame
import random
from alien import Alien
from time import sleep

from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Powerups(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, settings, bullets, center):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.type = random.choice(['speed', 'power_shot'])
        self.image = powerup_images[self.type]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  
        self.rect.center = center
    
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.speed_factor = 0.2

    
    def update(self):
        self.y += self.speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y

    powerup_images = {'speed': 
    pygame.image.load('images/speed_pwr.bmp'),
        'power_shot': pygame.image.load ('images/power_shot_pwr.bmp')}
```

Then the code which updates the spawned powerups every time the screen is updated:

```
def update_powerups(settings, powerups, ship, bullets, aliens, screen):
    powerups.update()

    for powerup in powerups.copy():
        if powerup.rect.top >= settings.screen_height:
            powerups.remove(powerup)


    check_powerup_ship_collisions(settings, screen, ship, bullets, 
    powerups)
```

and the code which checks if my ship has picked up a power-up, and then acts accordingly (I just have the speed power-up at the moment which should up the limit of your bullets for 10 seconds.):

```
def check_powerup_ship_collisions(settings, screen, ship, bullets, 
    powerups):

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, powerups):
        if Powerups(settings, bullets, ship.rect.center).type == 
           'speed':
            settings.bullet_limit = 100
            sleep(10)
            settings.bullet_limit = 3
```

If more is required then please tell me so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good places to start are the [tour] and [ask]. There's not really much anyone here can do to help, without seeing any of the code. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Do you have an exit() in your code someplace?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated my post with code, might be handy hahaha.

The problem might be with the line:

    `if Powerups(settings, bullets, ship.rect.center).type == 'speed':`

But I don't know how I can define center with a valid value.

Comment: Please look at the requirements for a [mre]. It doesn't have to be your *entire* code—removing unrelated parts and stripping it down to isolate the problem is an important step—but it does have to run on its own and demonstrate the behavior you describe. In other words, we should be able to copy and paste your code, make sure any dependencies are installed, run it, and see the incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

With the provided code it is not possible to reproduce the error. However I think the problem is in the following code

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, powerups):
    if Powerups(settings, bullets, ship.rect.center).type == 'speed':
```

Here you are creating a new instance of Powerups instead you just have to check the type of the object returned by `pygame,sprite.spritecollideany()` call. Instead try

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, powerups):
    collided_powerup = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ship, powerups, True)
    if collided_powerup.type == 'speed':
```

Comment: If I run this and pick up a powerup it gives me the error:

\
 line 182, in check_powerup_ship_collisions
    `if collided_powerup.type == 'speed':`

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: try `collided_powerup[0].type == 'speed':`

Comment: I think I have found the problem! I put the command `sleep(10)` to make the powerup last 10 seconds but I think that that just makes my game freeze for 10 seconds. Is there a better way to make the chosen feature last 10 seconds?